# Solving quadrature differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, mathematical-physics

I am trying to solve the velocity as a function of the time:
$$
ma=F_\text{Thrust}-F_\text{Drag}\Leftrightarrow m \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t} v(t) = \frac p {v(t)} - k\cdot(v(t))^2
$$

where
 $m$ is the mass [kg], $k$ is the drag coefficient and $p$ is the power [W]

I wonder if it is even possible to solve it analytical? If possible, how do I approach it?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as $m\dfrac{v}{p - kv^3} \dfrac {{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}= 1$, decompose $\dfrac{v}{p - kv^3}$ into partial fractions, and integrate.

Comment: Thanks. How do I decompose it as there is only one factor in the denominator?

Comment: @Hulla Watch closely. There are three factors.

Comment: I can only see one factor: (p-k*v^3) . I need two or more factors before I can decompose it.